# Set state inside zod SuperRefine or in a hook called by zod

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, zod

is there a way to set a state into the superRefine function or into a hook called by the zod schema?
By now when the zod schema calls the hook that set the state I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') at n (zod.ts:15:1) at zod.ts:77:1 at async _executeSchema (createFormControl.ts:381:1) at async Object.onChange (createFormControl.ts:718:1)

Is that normal? Is there a way to do this?

Zod version: 3.21.2

PS: Let me know if you need a codesandbox

I've tried set state inside the superRefine method and in a custom hook called by the zod superRefine function but i get the same error. Inside the hook I need to call an axios call to get some date and set them as state, so if you can suggest me another solution or if I'm doing something wrong it would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you have to `await` somewhere (or resolve a `Promise`). A mix of `async` and `undefined` means that something was not ready.

Answer (score 0):

I was already using await the problem was that the state was called in a nested function so I can't call a setState inside zod or in a custom hook called by zod.
What I'm trying to achieve is: after the user compile a specific field onBlur it's called an axios call an if this call goes well a do some action, but if it gives an error I set an error in the filed, the problem is that each time I set the error if the user submit the form or focus on the same field and than focus out the error disappears   and I what I want instead is to keep the error there if the value has not changed and also if the form submits but the value is still the same I need to see the error and prevent the user to submit the form.

Comment: This should either be a comment or added to your original question for clarification; not a response.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).